# So I have a unit but no project ?

Tags: delphi

In a lot of moving from hone memory stick to another I seemed to have lost my project 1 and now my unit 1 won't compile, any help on how to get a project 1 so that my unit can run ?

Comment: You need to recreate whatever is needed that you have lost. What you need depends on what your program does. Only you know. No two project files are identical. Some can differ markedly. If you want to know what a project file looks like, typically, create a new project and look at it.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you probably lost part of your project (though an easy to reconstruct one, if it's only .dpr). But that might be a big opportunity to start thinking about VCS. http://www.gitlab.com or http://www.bitbucket.org would be a nice start. :)

Comment: Chances are, if you've named your project the default `project1` then I would assume you've never modified the code there - so just create a new project and add your files to it. If you have changed the code there, you will have to re-write it.

Comment: Or if you have an old copy of this file, just use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been commented, it depends.  If you have not added a lot of modules to the project so that your *.dpr* file still looks like

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Then recovery is trivial. Create a new project, open its source, delete the existing unit, and add in the old unit. It should work. If you try it and you get messages about missing modules, add them to the project as needed.